# ASP.NET website References in Property Pages missing Remove button

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I just cloned and opened a solution that a colleague has been working on, and there are some references that seem to be misaligned. I wanted to remove and re-add references but when I go into the References list in Property Pages there aren't any buttons to manage the list.

[image]

This is what it looks like on the machine
[image]

How do I enable the Add, Remove, Update buttons?

Comment: Is the project currently running?

Comment: No, the project doesn't run on my machine. It runs on the other machine though. The differences in the list of references came from me trying to fix the references via the Add -> References... window, but I need to remove the old ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm feeling a little silly, but they do seem to have a bug in the window layout logic. I just needed to expand the size of the window.

[image]

Comment: I have to to thank you and this was the problem actually. I pulled my hairs for half an hour before finding this.... Incredible